# Is there a way to get around populating a collection on mongodb? I've tried using .populate() but it keeps returning an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is just a part of a large block of code of where I used the aforementioned method to see if I would be able to populate the collection. It's supposed to be a protected route hence the passport module. The code was suppose to populate the UserProfile module coming from a User module. The fields being added to the UserProfile are the name and avatar represented in the second argument of the mongodb method. I can't seem to find the error but it keeps returning an empty object but there are data of that collection. Here's the code:

```
router.get(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    //Load User profile
    const errors = {};

    UserProfile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
      .populate("user", ["name", "avatar"])
      .then((profile) => {
        if (!profile) {
          errors.noprofile = "This user does not have a profile yet";
          return res.status(404).json(errors);
        }

        res.json(profile);
      })
      .catch((err) => res.status(404).json(err));
  }
);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Is there a way to get around populating a collection in MongoDB?  It seems you are trying to query MongoDB.  This is a method asking for data, not saving data.  Are you saying the query is not working and not retrieving existing data, or are you saying you are not able to save data in MongoDB?

Comment: I'm saying it's unable to retrieve and populate the data i.e. increase a collection. if i remove the the .populate method from the code, it returns the original UserProfile collection. But if I try add back the  populate method because I want the field for the name and avatar to be part of the UserProfile field, it returns an empty object and throws an error.

Comment: Please also show the UserProfile and User schemas, and the error that you mentioned is thrown.

Comment: Try using `findById` instead of `findOne`

Comment: Thanks guys. I've figured it out. I made a typo for the collection I was trying to query. Instead of "users" I wrote "user".